# automatic paging functionality in C#

Tags: c#

I am confused with a flow. I have a list of student objects.

```
List<Student> StudentLists;
```

Intially i will be having 10 student objects in the list.

There is a button in C# 4.0 winform and when i clicks on the button,

i need to take first 3 student objects from the list and call a wcf service and send
these three student object to the wcf service.

I have implemented the wcf call back functionality.

After processing the web service, i will get the call back result for theose 3 student objects.

Each call back may come in different times.

Once i got all the three call back results from webservice, i want to take next 3 available
student object and do the same web service call...

I want to do it untill it processes all the 10 items from the lists.

But I know how to take each time 3 objects from the lists. It is like paging.

```
var students = StudentLists.Skip(skip).Take(3).ToArray();
```

But I am doing it in each time button click. In each button click, i will take next 3 objects.

Is there any way that to do all these steps without doing button click ?

Comment: You don't want any button click or you just don't want to have to click it multiple times?

Comment: first time i will start by clicking on button. First time it takes 3 items and do process and return the process result. but these results may come in different times. after all the 3 items completed, it should automatically take next 3 items and do the same process. Then next 3 until it finishes all the 10 items in the lists.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you want to process the students in batches, if this is the case you could write an extension method to do this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int batchSize)
{
    return items.Select((item, inx) => new { item, inx })
                .GroupBy(x => x.inx / batchSize)
                .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.item));
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach (var batch in StudentLists.Batch(3))
{
      //Do something with batch
      //Process
      //Get result etc...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the process result after wcf web service call back is getting in another block of code inside a method. That is the problem. First it will take 3 objects and send to wcf web service and returns the call. The web service will fire back the process result of each 3 objects as call back, which is getting fired inside another method.

Comment: You could easily check that you have the results from all 3 objects before moving onto the next batch within this loop. The call to the other methods will eventually return back to the foreach assuming no errors etc..